# Execute sql query in asp.net page

Tags: sql-server

How to run sql query from asp.net page?? i want to run all sql statements using asp.net web form , like select statement, Delete statement , insert statement and create a new table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Have you  made any attempt on your own to do this?

Comment: This question is a bit too broad and not really on topic for [so]. What you need is a tutorial, and there's plenty to be found around the net. If you want to know what type of questions that are suited for [so] see the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

> Just Try to Drag and Drop one table from database to Asp.net page (.aspx) and you will
>   get the sqldatasource  configuration that includes the edit, update
>   and delete code, the same way you can try the manipulation.